# Parse Log Out Button Not Changing Views

Tags: objective-c, xcode, authentication, parse-platform

I am using parse and I have a button linked to an IBAction as seen below. Although this does log the user out, it does not change screens as I was hoping it would by adding the popViewControllerAnimated. If Im not going about this properly, how would I bring the user back to the login/signup view controller? Thanks in advance!

```
- (IBAction)logOutButtonTapAction:(id)sender {
[PFUser logOut];

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

*Warning message with PACSPlashViewController:*

Warning: Attempt to present  on  while a presentation is in progress!
2014-09-09 22:25:57.391 XpironMobileV.2[76165:613] attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear. self =  modalViewController = 
2014-09-09 22:25:57.391 XpironMobileV.2[76165:613] attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear. self =  modalViewController =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the bring back the login/sign up view controller, you have to use the following code:

```
PFLogInViewController *logInController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
logInController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:logInController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You can read more about how to do this at parse.com user interface section in the docs.

**EDIT**

To do this with `PACSplashViewController`, you can simply import the view controller and use the following code below:

```
PACSplashViewController *logInController = [[PACSplashViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:logInController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: What if I had a custom view controller that presented the login and sign up views named: PACSplashViewController?

Comment: I updated the code and although it does get rid of the screen, it brings it to an all black screen and shows up with the warning I will put above ^

Comment: Where did you put this code in? Keep it in viewDidAppear.

Comment: I originally didn't have it in the viewDidAppear so I moved it and I am getting this new error: http://imgur.com/CifguUG

Comment: Thank you for your help, but any idea why this is so?

Comment: Well, you simply cannot have a method inside another method. Before you continue asking questions, I just wanted to ask you how long have you been learning objective-c and app programming? Because it seems like you don't have much experience on the subject and I suggest taking a course on it like Paul Hegarty's Stanford course which is free online at iTunes university.

Comment: I have watched 3 lessons of the stanford course so far... So considering that fact, I am just starting out. Also, if I cannot have a method within another method, how would I go about implementing the button in the viewDidAppear method? Thanks! :)

Comment: In the button action method, how about you call perform for segue and then perform a modal segue to the PACSplashViewController. By the way, towards the last lectures of the Stanford Course, they mention how to do a modal segue so you should check it out.

Comment: I ended up looking into it and I kept the [PFUser logOut]; part of the code, got rid of the rest, and then just control dragged a modal segue from the button and it worked perfectly! Cant believe I didn't try that earlier. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! If you can, you should possibly up vote this answer to make it helpful to other people encountering the same problem.